# Do neural nets require data to be sequential?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

I want to know if sequential data changes the output of a standard (not recurrent) neural network.

For instance, let's say I have a straight line with coordinates in the format:

```
x: 0, 1, 2, 3
y: 0, 1, 2, 3
```

Now I have another straight line, exactly the same as the first one, but with the points in a different order:

```
x: 0, 3, 1, 2
y: 0, 3, 1, 2
```

Will the neural network treat these the same when mapping to an output (i.e. ignore the fact that the coordinates are not in the same sequence)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough data and a big enough network it might learn to treat them the same. But a priori input in the first neuron will be treated differently from input in the second neuron. After all they have different weights. And even if it could learn to treat them the same, you should just sort the coordinates beforehand.